# Handling F5 in JQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

I have a site where I would like to override F5 so that it doesn't refresh the page, but instead executes some ajax calls to refresh certain pieces. Is this possible?

**EDIT:** Because none of you seem to understand why I would want to do something like this, if you are genuinely interested then visit these links:

Open-source project (simple web-terminal):
http://code.google.com/p/web-terminal

Running demo of simple web-terminal:
http://web-terminal.net.pine.arvixe.com

Live implementation (The forum version):
http://www.u413.com

Comment: Why? I don't want to override the refresh button, just the F5 key. In much the same way you can override the ENTER key and stop it from submitting a form so you can better handle the events asynchronously.

Comment: @Chevex That's hardly the same. I don't want some script altering how the function keys work; they are fundamental and largely *de facto* standardised. I also hope that this is not possible.

Comment: I think it actually is possible. But unless it's some kind of game and you will ALWAYS ensure old stuff is not cached: **Don't break F5!**

Comment: @Chevex: I think this is an extremely bad idea. As a user, I frequently press F5 to refresh and if it didn't perform as I expected, and it was the page's fault, then I am inclined to not ever visit that site ever again. Interfering with standard functionality is a bad idea. It akin to someone using ctrl-S for something other than save. In a browser, if I press F5, I want the page to refresh. Not some of it, all of it.

Comment: I get the impression from mention of the refresh button that `F5` does something similar to `Ctrl+R` or `Ctrl+Shift+R` (?) so if you code to catch F5 key presses you're going to miss other people's refreshes. An really, maybe `Ctrl+R` is OK but don't touch my `Ctrl+Shift+R` -- if I press that I *really* want a full reload and won't appreciate you trying to be helpful.

Comment: @alastair Alright fine, because I cannot explain it without showing you. Here is the project: http://www.u413.com

Comment: @Chevex Because if I hit F5, I want the thing to reload. Perhaps because the network hitched and stopped loading some content, or the website screwd something up etc. If the app wants to refresh just parts of something, it should have a Refresh button, Load more results button or similar.

Comment: The project is an all Ajax command prompt style forum board. The REFRESH command will reload a topic. I want to override F5 and force it to send the REFRESH command through the command line, instead. When people want to see the latest updates their instinct is to press F5, but that reloads the site and the whole web-terminal.

Comment: @nos, see my last two comments.

Comment: You can't remember its state somehow? @Downvoter: I can fully imagine that you don't agree with the OP about what he wants to do (or better: prevent), but that's not what downvotes were intended for: when a question is unclear. This one certainly isn't.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel No, this application is stateless for various reasons. It stores a command-line context in the client markup but is wiped on refresh. See my edit for more details if you really care that much.

Comment: @chevex: Ok, I can see why you would want this functionality. Maybe you could look at using cookies to store the current navigation state, then when they refresh, take them to that location. I still think it's a bad idea to interfere with what people expect their browser to do. As other people have said though, it's your web application. :)

Comment: @nos, you are not my target demographic.

Comment: @Alastair Pitts, I guess I just don't see the difference. People expect enter to submit the page for post back, but overriding that doesn't seem to annoy anyone. Besides, I'm responding to user complaints on the site, not just a random whim on my part. I do appreciate the feedback though.

Comment: I do like the idea of cookies. I could store command-line context there. Hmmm

Comment: To add to Alastair's comment (and that was what I was hinting at): it provides a more solid user experience when such a state is remembered. E.g., when I accidentally close the tab containing your forum, I'll have to navigate back to the topic I was after reopening the page.

Comment: @Marcel, true. That might be a good idea. I'm just not quite sure how I'll implement that yet, but I'm sure I can figure it out. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It looks like the question above is related to a web application.  That is a application whose UI is in the browser.    Opposed to a web-site, which is intended to be viewed by a larger audience, any browser, any OS etc. (web apps consider those too, but may have a more strict user base)

Comment: Web application means it is pre-compiled. It has nothing to do with browser compatibility, OS compatibility, traffic, etc. A "website" is compiled on the fly as users make requests. A web application is perfectly capable of handling very high traffic and is most certainly viewable in any browser. Though I don't really understand what any of this has to do with the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the same as the accepted answer above, except without capturing the 'keypress' event.

If you capture the 'keypress' event, you also block the 't' key.  For some reason both the keycode and ASCII keycode are both captured if you use the 'keypress' event (which you can't see in the chrome debugger).  The F5 key is '116', but the ASCII keycode for 't' is also 116, so with the 'keypress' event you block F5, but you also block 't' app-wide.

```
$(document).bind('keydown keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.which === 116) {
       console.log('blocked');
       return false;
    }
    if(e.which === 82 && e.ctrlKey) {
       console.log('blocked');
       return false;
    }
});
```

Here's the coffeescript just for fun :)

```
$(document).bind "keydown keyup", (e) ->
    if e.keyCode is 116
      console.log "blocked"
      return false
    if e.keyCode is 82 and e.ctrlKey
      console.log "blocked"
      false
```

Answer (score 10):

Well, you **could** do that (at least in some browsers, I'm not sure if this works cross-browser), but it reaaalllly would be a pretty bad user experience.

```
$(document).bind('keypress keydown keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.which === 116) {
       console.log('blocked');
       return false;
    }
    if(e.which === 82 && e.ctrlKey) {
       console.log('blocked');
       return false;
    }
});
```

Anyway, even if that works, there are other ways for an user to refresh the site. Pressing `ctrl + r` (`cmd + r`) or just hit the refresh button. Well, the other hot-key combination can get blocked similar, but no way to block the refresh button.

--

**It's maybe a huge better idea not to block those default browser behaviors, but to ask gracefully. That can be done by binding an event handler to the `onbeforeunload` event, which fires before a site is unloaded.**

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    return 'Are you really sure?';
});
```

Comment: AFAIK jQuery normalises the event object so it should be fine for x browser compatibility.

Comment: In my case it would not be a bad user experience. I won't go about promoting my own projects but in this case it would be great.

Comment: In Internet Explorer you also have to explicitly set the `keyCode` of the `Event` interface (aka `window.event`) to `0`, otherwise it won't prevent the page from refreshing. I don't know if jQuery takes care of that. A [quick look](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L463-478) at its source code reveals it doesn't seem so.

Comment: Yeah I don't care if they work around it to refresh, it's only for convenience of the user. Most complaints I'm getting are that their instinct is to press F5 but in this rich asynchronous environment they are being taken out of the experience when they do that.

Comment: @Chevex: if it's such a rich asynchronous evnrionment, surely you don't need your users to force refresh to get updated information,

Comment: @Chevex: it's your web application, it's your decision. I'm only saying it's totally apart from not being intuitive, because it's SO against the normal behavior.

Comment: @all-of-you see the comments I left on my own question. This isn't your normal web application.

Comment: I like your idea of asking if they are sure. That is actually a better idea. All I care about is that they have expressed frustration by their instinct to totally blow away their client session and have to re-issue the commands the entered to get where they were. This would prevent them from accidentally doing that.

Comment: +1 for the `onbeforeunload` suggestion, if I could; @Chevex: remember this (non-standard) event listener doesn't work in Opera, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example on how overriding the F5 key will enhance user experience. I'm building the newsletter editor for my client and I need to prevent the page from reloading when user accidentally presses F5 key but instead it refreshes email preview created from entered html code.